# change the text of the button which was clicked in a getView function android

Tags: android

I want to the change the text of the button which was clicked in a getView function. The text is changed but when the view is scrolled the text of other buttons which the same id is also changed. I don't want that. I want only the text of the button which was clicked to be changed.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


         final int i=position;   


            List dialog = DialogList.get(i);
            final Object memid = dialog.get(2).toString();
            final String dialogid = dialog.get(3).toString();
            final String dialogtype = dialog.get(4).toString();



    ImageView imageViews;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.invite_friends_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.friendsname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendsname);

        holder.profimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.member_image);
        holder.assign = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);

         convertView.setTag(holder);
    }


    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.friendsname.setText(user_name);

    holder.assign.setTag(holder);

    holder.assign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("assigntext", holder.assign.getText().toString());

            SharedPreferences prfs = _context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String token = prfs.getString("apptoken", "");
            String url = null;
            if(dialogtype.equals("V"))
            {
            url = "http://www.jjhjjkh.com/index.php?/alkjlkjlk/dialog/invjlkjlkjklialogmember?apptoken="
                        + token + "&dialogid=" + dialogid+"&mid="+memid.toString();
            }
            if(dialogtype.equals("P"))
            {
             url = "http://www.ckjhuihiuhiu.com/index.php?/kjij/dialog/inviuhuihuihuimember?apptoken="
                    + token + "&dialogid=" + dialogid+"&mid="+memid.toString();
            }
            List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
             Log.d("cat",url.toString());
            // JSON Node names
            String TAG_DETAILS = "invitemembers";
            String TAG_MSG = "msg";
            // contacts JSONArray
            JSONArray dialogpublish = null;
            JSONArray dialogs = null;
            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            // Log.d("cat",json.toString());

            try {
                dialogpublish = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DETAILS);

                // Log.d("apptoken",login.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < dialogpublish.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject d = dialogpublish.getJSONObject(i);

                    String msg = d.getString(TAG_MSG);
                    //dialogs = d.getJSONArray("updatedialog");
                    if (msg.equals("success")) {
                        // ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                        //Integer currentPos = view.getTag();
                        String mem_id= view.getTag().toString();
                        if(mem_id.equals(memid))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(_context, "Member invited Succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                         mH.assign.setText("Invited");

                        }
                         //view.setText("Invited");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: onClick lister u can do that na

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
String mem_id= view.getTag().toString();
if(mem_id.equals(memid))
{
    Toast.makeText(_context, "Member invited Succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
    ((Button)view).setText("Invited");
}
```

Comment: I am getting The method setText(String) is undefined for the type View

Comment: ((Button)view).setText("Invited");

Comment: public void onClick(final View view) try this

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is happenning because you are using the viewholder pattern. The viewholder pattern tends to cache views for performance optimization. try to write the adapter without using viewholder. If the list view items arent large in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new HashMap in Adapter :

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> buttonTitleMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Create a function getButtonTitle as below in Adapter :

```
private String getButtonTitle(int position){
    if(buttonTitleMap.containsKey(position)){
        return buttonTitleMap.get(position);
    }else{
        return "Your Normal Button text";
    }
}
```

Then in getView() of Adapter, befor returning convertView, call :

```
....
holder.assign.setText(getButtonTitle(position));
holder.friendsname.setTag(position);
return convertView;
}
```

When the Button is clicked, you can get the list item position of the button. So what you need to do is to change the button title as you do before and also update the hashmap with the same value :

```
holder.assign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ....
        mH.assign.setText("Invited");
        int position = (int)mH.friendsname.getTag();
        buttonTitleMap.put(position,"Invited");
        ....
    }
}
```

You are done.

Comment: I am getting integer cannot be cast to viewholder android at ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder)view.getTag(); line

Comment: Check my changed answer : Changes : holder.friendsname.setTag(position); and int position = (int)mH.friendsname.getTag();

Comment: i have done some changes in accordance to your answer but i am always getting the position of the last item in the listview, but now by button text is not changing on scroll. But the position is always of the last item. Can you pls guide?

Comment: I didnt understand...is it working in the way u expected?? I mean what is the issue that you are facing now?